# Web exception returned Not found on a Json Request with Windows Phone 8

Tags: json, exception, httpwebrequest, windows-phone, httpwebresponse

I tried to get and set Json but I have an exception on the "endgetresponse":

```
   public void GetSetJsonString (string message)
        {
        this.message = message; 
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myurl);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(myurl, myfirstcookie);
        request.CookieContainer.Add(myurl, mysecondcookie);
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

    }
    private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }

    private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string answer = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();
    }
}
```

On the line 
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

I obtained this exception:

{System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at project.GetSetJson.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_1b(Object state2)}

Curiously, when the Json message that I send as a mistake, I didn't have the exception and I received an error message from the server.

Did you have an idea why I have this exception and how I can resolve this problem?

Tank you very much!